# Error when placing value in a NUMBER variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  proj_ID VARCHAR2(5):=500;
  proj_name VARCHAR2(30); 
  pledge_count VARCHAR2(15);
  pledge_sum NUMBER(7,2);
  pledge_avg NUMBER(7,2);
BEGIN
  SELECT projname
    INTO proj_name
    FROM dd_project
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  SELECT COUNT(idproj)
    INTO pledge_count
    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(pledgeamt), '$999.99')
    INTO pledge_sum
    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

    SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(pledgeamt), '$999.99')
      INTO pledge_avg
      FROM dd_pledge
      WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Project ID: ' || proj_ID || ' Project Name: ' || proj_name || 'Pledge Count: ' || pledge_count
  || ' Total Dollars Pledged: ' || pledge_sum || ' Avg. Pledge Amount: ' || pledge_avg);
END;
```

I'm getting an Oracle error saying that I have an arithmetic issue and that I might be trying to store a value to a variable that isn't large enough. I'm confused because my SUM variable value ends up at $190.00 and my AVG variable value ends up at $63.33 (I've confirmed in separate SELECT statements). Shouldn't my declared pledge_sum and pledge_avg variables be large enough to store those values with a precision of 7 and scale of 2? Should NUMBER(7,2) hold a value that is as large as $99,999.99?

Am I not understanding when you'd use a NUMBER data type? Or am I off on what precision and scale actually mean?

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: pledge_sum and avg should be varchar type

Comment: @GurV I got it to work with VARCHAR2 type, but do you know the reason that wouldn't work with a NUMBER data type? Wouldn't you want to store a sum/avg values in NUMBER data type variables?

Comment: it won't work because you use `TO_CHAR(`

Comment: So if you were using a NUMBER data type, and wanted to add a $ sign, you'd just have to concatenate that to the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TO_CHAR(col, '$999.99')
```

The above formats the value from col to string and adds a currency character.

So, when to try to get this value into a number variable, you'll get a

> PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

because the string produced by to_char is not implicitly convertible into number.

You might wanna use `varchar2` instead.

```
pledge_sum varchar2(20);
pledge_avg varchar2(20);
```

or use to_char on the variables at the end.

```
DECLARE
  proj_ID VARCHAR2(5):=500;
  proj_name VARCHAR2(30); 
  pledge_count VARCHAR2(15);
  pledge_sum NUMBER(7,2);
  pledge_avg NUMBER(7,2);
BEGIN
  SELECT projname
    INTO proj_name
    FROM dd_project
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  SELECT COUNT(idproj)
    INTO pledge_count
    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  SELECT SUM(pledgeamt)
    INTO pledge_sum
    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

    SELECT AVG(pledgeamt)
      INTO pledge_avg
      FROM dd_pledge
      WHERE idproj = proj_ID;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Project ID: ' || proj_ID || ' Project Name: ' || proj_name || 'Pledge Count: ' || pledge_count
  || ' Total Dollars Pledged: ' || to_char(pledge_sum, '$999.99') || ' Avg. Pledge Amount: ' || to_char(pledge_avg, '$999.99'));
END;
```